# Cells.Find works, but how do I use Range.Find?

Tags: vba, excel

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

works very well for finding the last row in a worksheet. But how can I tweak the line above to find the last row of column C?

I've tried

```
LastRow = Range("C:C").Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

but I get the error message Incompatible types

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: He doesn't write how to find the last row of only a certain column

Comment: He wrote it. See section `Find Last Row in a Column`: `LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because After is set to **[A1]**. This should be **[C1]**

```
LastRow = Range("C:C").Find("*", [C1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

another way

```
lrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: This won't throw error :) **lrow = Range("C" & 'Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row**

Comment: As I laready mentioned, this Q supposed to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Perfect! I got an error because the column was empty, but otherwise the method works fine

Comment: Do I have to write [C1]. I saw that it was an optional variable.

Comment: You can ignore.. As mentioned by @simoco this link explain has lot of examples.you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba